# Dealing with returned JSON data from PHP - AJAX JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been trying to retrieve json data from php.  I have a an HTML table which opens a modal.  I'm passing the id of the data in the row via ajax post, within the php file i plan to look up the relevant row in my database using the passed id and return all the information to dispaly in the modal. Currently ive been trying to just return the id back along with some temp values.

Javascript:

```
 var id = recipient;
 console.log("id: " + id);
 var idObject = { id: id }

 $.ajax({
 url: "json.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: idObject,
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json"    
 })
```

json.php:

```
<?php


    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $firstName = "firstname";
    $lastName = "lastname";
    $email = "email@hotmail.co.uk";



    if(isset($id)){
        $data = array(
            "id"     => $id,
            "firstName"  => $firstName,
            "lastName"   => $lastName,
            "email"      => $email
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

I tried using success to call a function but not had any luck.  Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: How is the Javascript / jQuery being fired - maybe post some more code.

Also, in your jQuery you need to handle the return of the AJAX call.

Comment: If you are getting json in ajax success then what is the problem \

Comment: What's the error you are getting if success is getting executed on ajax call then r u getting the right data just alert it .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "json.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: {id: id},
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json"    
 }).success(function(data){
    //data is now a JSON object containing data 
    //you outputted from PHP, example:
    $('#form-email').val(data.email); 
 });
```

also consider using HTTP status codes or returning `status` field in your JSON even when there's no `$id` set, so you have consistent response.

Example **(using `PHP 5.4+` short array syntax)**:

```
if(isset($id))
{
   return json_encode([
        'status' => 'ok',
        'errors' => [],
        //(rest of data)
   ]);
}
else 
{
   return json_encode([
        'status' => 'error',
        'errors' => ['no id given'],
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a PHP 5.4+ clause on the example for returning status. You will end up with down votes because "it doesn't work!" when someone finds this and is running 5.3 or something.